# how to solve this exponential inequality?

Tags: inequality, education

I'm studying for the admission test.
In particular, this exponential inequality is a little bit tricky.
this is the inequality:
$$
\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^x > 1 
$$
I've tried to use the change of basis formula to try to solve the logarithm to deduce the result. But it's not the optimal way.
Then, I've tried to rewrite 1 as (2/e)^0, and to solve the equation to find the critical point, but it's still not correct.
Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rember that $2/e$  is just a number. Call it $a$. Can you solve $a^x>1$ ?

Comment: a^x = 0, so x<0 or x>0 (because of the sign of the inequality) 
therefore, the solution would be equal to "always except for x=0".  The modus operandi would be the same for 2/e. Okay, got it. Thanks

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini Nope you are wrong. You did not calculate the number correctly.

Comment: @MattiP. No 2/e is not just a number. it is a number below 1. which means giving it a positive exponent will make it converge to 0. I dont know how you got 2 + on your answer.

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini Please resubmit your final solution when you're done.

Comment: @ombk you mean that I have to edit the answer and add the solution?

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini you can just add an additional answer below mine. for the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is answered in the comment but it isn't clear.

Since $2/e$ is less than 1 therefore, if we go with $x>0$ in the comments for any $x$, it would yield a wrong result. For example $(2/e)^{50} = 2.17*10^{-7} \leq 1$

However, for $x < 0$ as a first step, should be a good answer, since the equation will be inversed making it $e/2$ which is number over 1 in the first place.

Start from here.

***Continuation***

I said start from here, when I gave the full answer without supporting it (proof). Therefore, please rewrite everything in an eloquent way.